# How do I resize every frame in a Flash animation?

Tags: flash, adobe-flash

I have Flash CS3, and I just put together my first animation, totaling a little over 3,300 frames. Now I'm hoping to export the video to YouTube, but realized that I animated it with the default settings and default stage size of 550x400, which is probably not the ideal resolution. Ideally I'd like it be able to display in 1080p quality on YouTube (1280x720), and I don't see why this couldn't be possible since it's all vector graphics. But since the whole thing is already animated in 550x400, is there some way I can just batch resize all of it? Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! There's a feature on the timeline called "Edit Multiple Frames." Editing 3,330+ frames simultaneously is pretty slow, but since it was a one-time edit it got the job done.